# using value from script in jade template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, pug

I'm very new in jade, and I have came a cross some trouble with that, I have such `script` code in my jade template

```
script.
     function processInfo() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/dataLoader/scheduler/proccesInfo/' + #{project.Id},
            type: "POST",
            data: null,
            cache: false
        }).done(function (msg) {
            if  ($.trim(msg)) {
                //$("#processInfoPanel").html(msg);
                var a = msg;
                console.log(a);
            }
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.error("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
    }
```

I have to get the value of `a` variable in my jade template above

```
 tr
            th Processes
            td
                h3= #{a} 
                    case #{a}
                        when '': span.label.label-warning None
                        when null: span.label.label-warning None
                        default: span#processInfoPanel.label.label-success
```

I have used like that but it's incorrect syntax((((
How can I get it? Thanks!

Comment: Not able to understand your question, would you be more descriptive, and share a link of templating thing you are using

Comment: well, I have only one jade file, above this file I wrote script code and below this script my jade code. Then,  a  variable which I've created change every time, for example, if a variable has any value I need to get this value on my jade template in order to work with it

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on whether you are writing client side or server side javascript.

From what I can tell you are writing client-side.. in which case #{ } is less applicable.  Standard DOM - Manipulation may be the best approach here...

```
var h3 = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');
h3.innerHTML = a
```

Since its an AJAX call though, you may just need to `return a` in object literal notation.

`response {variableOfChoice: a}`
then
`#{variableOfChoice}`

This is straight javascript, so applying the same method in jQuery syntax should work.